# Tabela de frequência - Python

Tags: python-3.x, data.frame

Olá, sou iniciante na área de programação e estou com dificuldade para fazer uma tabela de frequência.

A tabela é essa:

```
import math
import statistics
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import pandas as pd

escolaridade = {
  'Grau de escolaridade' : ['Primário', 'Secundário', 'Superior'],
   'Urbano' : [5025, 3155, 1720], 
   'Rural' : [2580, 285, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(escolaridade)
df
```

Preciso calcular:

Proporção e % de indivíduos e cada grau de escolaridade, além de algumas proporções, mas sequer consegui fazer a soma dos valores para desenvolver os cálculos.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Essa é apenas uma das ideias que você pode utilizar:

Copiando o dataframe para o original ficar intácto:

```
df1 = df.copy()
```

Somando as linhas:

```
df1['Total'] = df1.sum(axis = 1)
```

Somando as colunas e criando uma nova linha no dataframe:

```
df1 = df1.append(df1.sum(axis = 0), ignore_index = True)
```

Setando 'Grau de escolaridade' como index:

```
df1.set_index('Grau de escolaridade', inplace = True)
```

Renomeando o index da nova linha:

```
 df1.rename(index = {'PrimárioSecundárioSuperior': 'Total'}, inplace = True)
```

Calculando a frequência:

```
df1['% Urbano'] =  round(df1['Urbano'] / df1['Total'],4) * 100
df1['% Rural'] = round(df1['Rural'] / df1['Total'],4) * 100
```

Saída:

```
                      Urbano    Rural   Total   % Urbano    % Rural
Grau de escolaridade                    
            Primário    5025    2580    7605       66.07    33.93
            Secundário  3155    285     3440       91.72    8.28
            Superior    1720    20      1740       98.85    1.15
               Total    9900    2885    12785      77.43    22.57
```